# How can I get the last value from a node with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml with a node named "Value" which comes in several places in the xml. However, I need to select the node "Value" which is under the node "Name = werkweeknummer". I have tried multiple things, but it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice">
      <xsl:if test="cbc:IssueDate"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(cbc:IssueDate,1,4),'W',cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value)"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried this with substring-lenghts(node name) - 1) but it doesn't get the last 2 characters --> which in my case would be the result I wanted, but instead it gives it gives 12 as a result.

```
 <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>121</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">+1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">+64.30</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:DespatchLineReference>
      <cbc:LineID/>
      <cac:DocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>101992936-0</cbc:ID>
      </cac:DocumentReference>
    </cac:DespatchLineReference>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">+13.50</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Name>Toeslag ADV percentage</cbc:Name>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5305" schemeAgencyID="6">S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>+21.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID schemeID="UN/ECE 5153" schemeAgencyID="6">VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        <cbc:Name>geboortedatum</cbc:Name>
        <cbc:Value>1984-10-12</cbc:Value>
      </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
      <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        <cbc:Name>Postcode Plaats</cbc:Name>
        <cbc:Value>1234 AA BLABLA</cbc:Value>
      </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
      <cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
        <cbc:Name>werkweeknummer</cbc:Name>
        <cbc:Value>16</cbc:Value>
      </cac:AdditionalItemProperty>
    </cac:Item>
```

This is the XML with the mentioned node with the same name (above, node name = value)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice">
      <xsl:if test="cbc:IssueDate"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(cbc:IssueDate,1,4),'W',cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value)"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have this now as my code, but the result is 2019W1980-02-12. I want to have 2019W16 (16 is the value from the last node with the same name, which is under "werkweeknummer"). I tried using the substring-length formula but then it gives 12 as a result --> 2019W12..

Comment: 1. The provided "xml" is not a well-formed xml document. 2. No "Invoice" element is present. 3. No "IssueDate" element is pesent. 4. No instance of the wanted transformation result is provided. These facts probably led to the absence of any definite answer so far. If not only *guesses* are wanted, this question needs to be stated in a clear, complete, correct and unambiguous way.

Answer (score 0):

The current expression you are using; `cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value`; will return three nodes. In XSLT 1.0, where you use a function (`concat` in this case) that expects a string as an argument, then if you pass in a node-set instead it will use the string value of the first node only. (In XSLT 2.0, you would have got an error).

The expression you want though, is this...

```
cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemProperty[cbc:Name='werkweeknummer']/cbc:Value
```

Do note you can simplify your current template to this....

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice[cbc:IssueDate]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(cbc:IssueDate,1,4),'W',cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemProperty[cbc:Name='werkweeknummer']/cbc:Value)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi tim, I tried to add your expression to mines, but Im now gettin 2019W, so the value from the node isn't been showing up (result should be 2019W16) <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice">
      <xsl:if test="cbc:IssueDate"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(cbc:IssueDate,1,4),'W',cac:AdditionalItemProperty[cbc:Name ='werlweeknummer']/cbc:Value)"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Comment: It should probably be `cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item/cac:AdditionalItemProperty/cbc:Value`